# Can I share my cable internet connection through my ADSL wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, networking, internet-connection, adsl, cable-modem

Over the xmas period I am at my in-laws. They have Virgin Broadband (cable) and have a basic modem / router that is plugged directly into their computer using an ethernet cable.

My wife and I arrived with 5 PCs! (ok, one is a gift and won't be used) 4 of which are laptops so I would like to be able to use their internet connection.

At the moment I am working so have plugged the ethernet cable into my work laptop. Rebooting the router meant that my work laptop now has internet.

I have my ADSL Netgear router which is wireless. I tried plugging it in between the router and the PC but I didn't seem to be able to share the internet connection wirelessly. The original PC still had internet despite ony being connected to my router but my wireless laptop didn't have a connection.

My old cable router had an internet ethernet port on the back that the modem plugged into. My ADSL router doesn't, it has a phone connection socket.

Is there a way of doing what I want with the equipment I have?

Thanks

Comment: Is your netgear Router a Router or a modem? Because it should just create a NAT and then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot substitute a Cable modem for an ADSL modem or visa versa (a Cable router is just a router with a built in cable modem, as is the same respectively for an ADSL router). They are two completely different technologies (a Cable modem syncs with CMTS and an ADSL modem syncs with a DSLAM).

You also cannot use the WAN port on a modem/router combination as if it were a standard router as it is looking for a different type of signal (that from a CMTS or DSLAM depending on the type of modem, it is not an Ethernet protocol).

You will need to purchase an ordinary router to place in between the PC and the ISP provided device. You will also need to make sure that they are in different subnets (ie, the cable modem/router will be using DHCP/NAT with 192.168.0.1 as the gateway, your router will accept a lease on the WAN and hand out DHCP/NAT on the LAN with 192.168.1.1 as the gateway).

Answer (score 1):

I am about 6 months out, but I think Community just bumped this...

Moab is correct, NTL/Virgin at the moment use MAC address restrictions and it can be a pain to get around. Sometimes it requires just restarting the modem, sometimes a phonecall to their very unhelpful support line, sometimes you need to go to a webpage (redirect on first connect) and other times it takes a few prayers!

If you want to connect multiple computers to it, by far the easiest solution is to get a RJ45 router (Sometimes called a cable router) which simply has a RJ45 instead of a RJ11 socket for the uplink. Before connecting the uplink, go to the routers control panel and forge the MAC address of the WAN/Uplink port to be the same as the computer you previous had connected.

When you plug the NTL/Virgin cable in to the router, it should share and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

See this article, some Cable providers only allow one computer (ip address) to be connected.

.

http://www.velocityguide.com/dsl/setup-dsl-with-wireless-router.html

Comment: Thanks but they are not a DSL provider, they are a Cable provider. The connection is not over phone lines but fibre optic to the street then coaxial to the house.

Comment: They definitely do allow multiple IPs to be connected as well, until recently when I moved I was a customer with them.

Comment: Instructions work for cable as well. Thanks for the down vote

Comment: I didn't give it a downvote, I don't think I have enough rep to do that on this site.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the article?

Comment: Theoretically, it should work. Ethernet cable from Cable Modem -> Wireless router -> Wi Fi connection.